# How to connect to multiple channels using websocket multiprocessing?

Tags: python, websocket, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I wrote a script allowing to collect data through different websockets channels but I can't manage to listen to multiple channel at once with this script. I would like to find a solution such as "multiprocessing" or "thread".

I managed to listen to several channel by running several times the script in different terminals.
For example if I want to listen to 10 channels, I launch 10 times the script with the desired channel as input argument, but I am sure there must be a smarter and cleaner way to do so using multiprocessing or other process.
Indeed, if I launch to many terminals my computer starts being really slow and the finality of this program would be to run it with a Raspberry Pi which is less powerful than my laptop.

The script is the following:

```
import websocket
import sys


def getData(uri, channel, pathCSV):

    ws = websocket.create_connection(uri)
    try:
        print("Sending data")
        ws.send(channel)
        print("Receiving...")
        result =  ws.recv()
        print ("Received '%s'" % result)
        while True:
            result =  ast.literal_eval(ws.recv())
            print("Received ast '%s'" % result)
            # Here is a function which write the collected data to 
            #  a CSV.
            exportDataToCSV(result, pathCSV)
    except websocket.WebSocketConnectionClosedException as e:
        print('This caught the exception')
        ws.close()
        # In case of error I simply relaunch the script
        getMarketData(uri, channel, pathCSV)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ws.close()
        return(result)

pathCSV = "/path/to/CSV"
uri = "websocket adress"
channelList = ["channel1", "channel2", "channel3", "channel4", 
"channel5"]

#channel : for now I have to select one

while True:
        getData(uri, channel, pathCSV)
```

So the question is "How can I manage to listen to all channels in only one instance of the script designed to collect and write received data to a CSV?".

Thank you in advance if you have any ideas to share.

Edit:

I found some information with "asyncio" library which lead me to the following code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import ast


uri = "websocket uri"
channelList = ["channel1", "channel2", "channel3", "channel4", 
               "channel5"]

async def getData(channelList):
    uri = "websocket uri"
    for channel in channelList:
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as ws:
                await ws.send(channel)
                print("Receiving...")
                result = await ws.recv() 
                # Confirmation ofsubscription 
                print ("Received '%s'" % result)    
                result =  ast.literal_eval(await ws.recv())  
                # Getting Data
                print("Received ast '%s'" % result)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(getData(channelList))
```

This way I can subscribe and listen to all channels by launching only one script. 
But this doesn't really help because in each loop I have to reconnect to the channel and if a channel took to long to answer I am missing lots of information from the other channels while I am not connected to them.

Could anyone help me to optimize the process?